# 501 Syntax error - line too long

Tags: php, email, smtp

While sending mail through php I am getting below error-

```
501 Syntax error - line too long 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 501 Syntax error - line too long 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

As above message clearly explains the issue but I don't want to reduce the content of html template. Any idea where I need to change settings ?

I am using these details-

```
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
                'smtp_port' => '587',
```

Comment: You could just spread the content over several lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the template code itself, you likely need to break the content over several lines by adding in some newline characters.

It's fairly easy to accidentally create very long lines, for example when you have a loop `echo`ing out content, or appending content to a string. Check these situations first. New lines can be added by `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL`, and won't affect the formatting of your html.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using PHP, you can use [chunk_split](http://php.net/chunk_split) to break up a long string of continuous characters.

We had this recently when trying to send attachments through AWS' SES.  Only one of five recipient servers rejected the email for having more than 1,000 characters (including the \r\n - 998 excluding).  Gmail, Outlook, yahoo all had no problem with it. We applied chunk_split to the base64_encode results and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Ran into this as well with AWS SES and it resolved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if the e-mail activity that you sent has more than 998 **continuous characters** in the e-mail activity message body.

998 characters allows for the required CR LF at the end of each line.

Try to wrap long lines.