# PHP mail function fails with "message has lines too long for transport"

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 7.4.30 and I'm totally new to PHP.

```
$subject ="My subject";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; background-color: #fff;">';
$message .= '<div class="info">&nbsp;</div>';
$message .= '<table style="text-align: justify; margin: auto; background-color: #ebebeb; border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; width: 600px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ebebeb" align="center">';
$message .= '<tbody>';
$message .= '<tr style="line-height: 0px;">';
$message .= '<td style="line-height: 0';


$from = "My website<robot@website.com>";
$replyto = "website@website.com"; 

$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $replyto . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: xxx@xxx.com'; 

$message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Looking at the delivery track from the server, I see the error message:

```
"message has lines too long for transport"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [501 Syntax error - line too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661264/501-syntax-error-line-too-long)

Comment: Thanks, it seems the issue is similar, but my PHP skills are basic. I guess I have to add "\n" at the end of each line?

Comment: Try and use `chunk_split` on your `$message` value, like suggested there. `$message = chnuk_split($message, 998);`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much! Chaged chnuk to chunk

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced this issue. An easy solution to this issue is replacing this line

`$message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);`

with

`$message = wordwrap($message, 70,"\r\n");`